# Django Models - How do you add subtype choice when user selects choice?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm working on a project where they have various job types that I've tackled with CHOICES, however, I want to add conditionals for WHEN job type 1 is chosen, SUBTYPES x-y become choices. I am having trouble with the syntax of how you would do that. I've included my pseudocode below... I appreciate any help!

```html
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jobs')
    JOB_CHOICES = (
        ('carpentry', 'Carpentry'),
        ('cleaning', 'Cleaning'),
        ('electrician', 'Electrician'),
        ('handyman', 'Handyman'),
        ('hvac', 'HVAC'),
        ('painting', 'Painting'),
        ('pest', 'Pest'),
        ('plumbing', 'Plumbing'),
        ('roofing', 'Roofing'),
        ('property', 'Property'),
    )
    jobType = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=JOB_CHOICES, default='handyman')
    # If JobType = Carpentry:
    # CARPENTRY_CHOICES = (
    #     ('trim', 'trim')
    #     ('sheetrock', 'Sheetrock')
    #     ('windows', 'Windows')
    #     ('doors', 'Doors')
    #     ('cabinets and shelving', 'Cabinets and Shelving')
    #     ('other', 'Other')
    # )
    # jobType = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CARPENTRY_CHOICES, default='other')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Django Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkaSK.png)

[Django Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulcDE.png)

[/api editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umB1B.png)

Comment: I suggest you add another `select` field which you can change the value according to the selected job type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with a job_type model, which has a name and a 'subtype' field.

```
class JobType(models.Model):
    SubTypeChoices = (...)
    name = models.CharField()
    subtype = models.CharField(choices=SubTypeChoices, ...)

class Job(models.Model):
    ....
    job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobType, ...)
    ....
```

This way you can associate your 'subtypes' with one job_type. And if for some reason you can have several job_types for a Job, use a ManyToMany field.